# How can i burn directory and files to DVD with another disc name in ubuntu 16.04 via terminal?

Tags: command-line, dvd, burning

I want do these in terminal:

- eject DVD-RW
- Check DVD disc blank or not
- Burn DVD if it blank (with any name I give)

But when I burn DVD with command `sudo wodim  dev=/dev/sr0 -v -data /path/to/data/` I cannot choose the disc name. I burn a DVD and open it, I saw the disc name is CD-ROM. How can I set disc name?
And I don't want create ISO file because my data files is big!

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: Thanks @David Foerster! My question just is "Can i set disc name when burn DVD via terminal?" But i'm not well in English, i'm sorry. I just want find way to burn data to dvd with my disc name. :D  If that not enought i can delete this and create another post but i think it not need because i bad in English and i'm sorry about it, again. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to clarify what your *actual and only* question (or set of closely related questions) is? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`genisoimage` has a `-V` option that specifies a volume label for the ISO. You can use this program to create ISOs for the data you want to burn and let `wodim` work with the images.

```
-V volid
    Specifies the volume ID (volume name or  label)  to  be  written
    into  the  master  block.   There  is  space  for 32 characters.
    Equivalent to VOLI in the .genisoimagerc file.  The volume ID is
    used  as  the mount point by the Solaris volume manager and as a
    label assigned to a disc on various other platforms such as Win‐
    dows and Apple Mac OS.
```

Comment: so i need make a iso file and burn it. Does have another way? i don't want make iso file, my data files is big.